# with proper path also django-admin command is not recognized

Tags: python, django, anaconda

I have kept anaconda(python) in django folder and have added path using setx command.

Even when I am running which python and which conda commands in cmd prompt,those are running fine. But "django-admin proj website" command is not recognized

snapshot of path variable-

C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ESCRIBA\composer\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SoftphoneSDK\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools;C:\android-sdk\tools\;C:\android-sdk\platform-tools\;D:\Appium\node_modules\appium\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\SafeCom\SafeComPrintClient;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;C:\extra softwares\apache-ant-1.10.1\bin;C:\Users\robhanda\django;C:\Users\robhanda\django\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\robhanda\django\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\robhanda\django\Library\bin;C:\Users\robhanda\django\Scripts;C:\Users\robhanda\django\Scripts;C:\Users\robhanda\django

Answer (score 0):

Try installing django in a virtual environment before running that command.